# Update values into MySQL with Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update

The `final_result` contains three URLS which I extract data from, this three numbers extracted should be updated into the three rows in column `trg`.

The code below somewhat works but the problems is that it updates all three rows with the data from the first URL instead of url1 to row1, url2 to row2 etc.

```
test = []
for url in final_result:
    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

    trg = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'someClass'})
    for ind in trg:
        insert = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', str(ind))
        test.append(insert)
        print(type(test))
        print(test)

    for values in test:
         cursor.execute("UPDATE my_table SET trg=%s", (values,))
         connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

**Results from `print(type(test))`**

```
<class 'list'>
```

**Results from `print(test)`**

```
['118\xa0732\xa0173']
['118\xa0732\xa0173', '676\xa0595']
['118\xa0732\xa0173', '676\xa0595', '314\xa0541']
```

**Ongoing work on Nathaniel F second solution**

```
test = trg
for i in range(len(final_result)):
    url = final_result[i]
    for url in final_result:
        sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
    for ind in oms:
        insert = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', str(trg[i]))
        test[i] = insert
    cursor.execute("UPDATE my_table SET trg=%s", (test))
    connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: the first fails because you must write ['100\xa150\xa194',] with a comma the second fails because you have ony one %s. and so on, see that you have only one parameter in your test, with a comma

Comment: Hi @nbk I Updated my code, with a for-loop and also added , to the query. No errors but it inserts the same value for all rows.

Comment: Look into your mysql server and use SHOW BINLOG EVENTS LIMIT 0,100 to see if your updates reached your server.

Comment: Not using binary logging it seems, but the data gets inserted. Only problem is that it updates all three row with the same data.

Comment: yes, this is what your command does. it updates every row with the same data. You must get the id oif every riw prior to updat eand add a where clause to update only one row at a time

Comment: @nbk Not sure how to fit in a WHERE clause in my case though...

Comment: It is hard to explain without kowing the structure of .my_table but you want the first value '118\xa0732\xa0173' to be added to the first row. now you must know  the idetifier for that row sa id so that your query looks like cursor.execute("UPDATE my_table SET trg=%s WHERE id = %s", (values,idfromrow)); so you select all ids and use an attay of the ids ti be used in every for loopo

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Error is caused by updating `test` without resetting it.

Each time you iterate through the loop, it's appending more values to the array, and eventually assigning more than MySQL is able to use, hence the `not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`.

As for why all three columns are being updated, it looks like it's probably caused by trying to update the entire column every time an individual value needs to be changed. I would suggest either using `WHERE` in your SQL statement to only update the cell that needs to be changed, which would look something like this (my MySQL is a bit rusty, but the general idea):

```
    UPDATE trg
    FROM my_table
    WHERE primary_key = %s # row_index
    SET trg = %s # updated value
```

The other option would be to save the values to `test` outside of the loop for the URLs, and update it once per URL/Index pair, and then run your existing SQL query to update the entire column at once:

```
    ...
    test = trg
    for i in range(len(final_result)):
        url = final_result[i]
        ...
        insert = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', str(trg[i]))
        test[i] = insert
    ...
    cursor.execute("UPDATE my_table SET trg=%s", (test))
    ...
```

A visual representation of the three methods:

```
    Original Column: ABC
    Result Column: XYZ

    Original Implementation:
    ABC --X-> "Set ABC = XBC" --Y-> "Set XBC = XYC" --Z-> "Set XYC = XYZ"

    SQL Change Using WHERE:
    ABC --X-> "Set A = X" --> XBC --Y-> "Set B = Y" --> XYC --Z-> "Set C = Z" --> XYZ

    Change Using Moved SQL:
    Database Values:
        ABC --X-> ABC --Y-> ABC --Z-> ABC --> "Set ABC = XYZ"
    Local Variable:
        ABC --X-> "Set A = X" --> XBC --Y-> "Set B = Y" --> XYC --Z-> "Set C = Z" --> XYZ
```

Comment: Ah, I see where I messed up. I am elaborating with your second solution. test = trg gives me "NameError: trg is not defined" however.

Comment: Updated the code so that you can see your second solution

Comment: Lets say I want to update all rows in my table every 15 minutes, how would I use WHERE statement? Since I can't really hardcode any certain row ID to it.